# Android RTSP to v4l2 device

Tags: android, ffmpeg, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I have created an application that takes an RTSP stream and displays it SurfaceView. This is straightforward enough. However I was wondering if it was possible to take an RTSP stream in Android and use it to create a v4l2-device in the same way connecting a webcam does at a location such as /dev/video0.

Can this be done using a compiled version of FFMPEG for Android or perhaps a simpler method?

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated!